# Traefik proxy ip auth

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a traefik in docker-compose:

```
 version: '3'
    networks:
      proxy:
        driver: bridge
    services:
      traefik:
        container_name: traefik
        image: traefik:v1.7.9
        command: --api --docker
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
          - ./acme.json:/acme.json
         networks: 
          - proxy
```

Also have nginx under mydomain.com, and I want to allow only my ip to connect to it:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    networks:
      - backend
      - traefik_proxy
    restart: always
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.port: "80"
      traefik.frontend.headers.allowedHosts: "1.2.3.4" # MyIp
      traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:mysite.com,www.mysite.com"
```

When I access mysite.com I got Bad Host error, and the IP in headers is my server's ip instead of my real ip. 
P.S Docker in swarm mode, but nginx and traefik build using local docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add following directives to nginx docker-compose:

```
traefik.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange: "1.2.3.4" # my Ip
traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: true
traefik.frontend.whiteList.useXForwardedFor: "true"
```